# Foreach Looping over the same excel file twice

Tags: foreach, ssis, sql-server-data-tools

I am having weird issue with some of the SSIS packages I have set up. The issue is that the for each loop is looping over the same excel file twice. There is only one file in the source folder.

With the excel file path variable on my excel connection string, the data flow task fails, as its unable to acquire connection the to the file the second time. (Connection was already established the first time).

If I remove the file path variable, and point the connection manager straight to the file, it runs, however loops over the same file twice before moving on to the next section. When looking at the data in the temp table, its clear that there are duplicate values from both iterations of the loop.

Anyone ever experienced this before or know hoe to fix it? I have many packages running daily for different set of data and they all use the same method to pick up excel files, yet one or two of these are displaying this issue?

Comment: Could be issue with file path variable, does it have dates, can you share it please ?

Comment: Perhaps pictures of your control flow in general and then specifically how your foreach file enumerator is configured and then show the Excel Connection Manager -> Properties -> Expressions

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your control flow looks like this

[image]

And your data flow looks like this

[image]

Please double check that you have set up your foreach loop container correctly.

[image: ForeachFileLoopContainer]

[image: ForeachFileLoopContainer2]

And that you have setup your expression on your excel connection manager correctly.

[image: ExcelConnector]

Hope this helps,

Jesse